# Why is the CW mechanism so counter-intuitive?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

Being primarily a SO user, I haven't experienced community wiki that much before, hence it never got me thinking. But since those times are gone now, there's something about CW that just doesn't add up and I can't figure out (or find) why:

- do we **keep** reputation gained before CW-conversion, yet **stop** gaining any new
- ... at the same time, we **lose** all the points accumulated towards the tags of the question
- ... and, surprisingly we're still allowed to gain badges for CW-converted questions/answers (even tho it might be result of "community effort")

I started thinking what is the rationale behind that (and why is it so inconsistent and counter-intuitive) and all I could come up with was [*"wat?"*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXEgk1Hdze0).

Question is - why does it have to be so confusing for the user? Why is reputation kept (just as if we were being told *"This was fairly earned reputation you got there, we let you keep it"*) while at the same time tag-points for that reputation are not (apparently not as fairly gained). Why can we still gain badges, but not rep (looks almost like comforting *"CW is not that bad, you can still get something - just not the rep!"*). Why should we gain anything at all for possibly a community effort?

Shouldn't the system be simple? CW kicks in, you either:

- keep all you had, yet stop gaining anything new
- lose all you had and not gain anything new
- no change to how non-cw question/answer would work

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: CW was broken to begin with, and has been abused in every way it could. Now it's more of a relic of the past than something useful...

Comment: @Yannis Rizos: Bingo! 1000% correct.

Comment: CW seems to have always been a solution in search of a problem; the "problem" it did solve (questions without answers) were determined to be really bad for the network and thus CW has pretty much died. It has a couple odd uses (allowing people to edit your meta posts without enough rep for one) but that's about it